# How to display questions and answers in Listview (in Xamarin.Forms)?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm trying to connect something with something. I added a button in one list from which I would like it to redirect to another page. In this second page I would like to display a list of questions and answers related to the previous page where I have "Routes" In the api from questions and answers I have RouteId which I associated with pressing the route.id button (tmp.RouteId == route.Id) 
My api responsible for questions and answers from RouteId:

```
{"Id":1,"Question1":"W którym roku?","AnswersString":"1987,1980,1957","Answers":["1987","1980","1957"],"GoodAnswer":2,"Correct":null,"RouteId":212,"Route":null}
```

I only pull out of it (Answers, Question 1, Good Answer)

The code responsible for pressing the button on the list page:

```
 private async void OnQuizClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         var button = sender as ImageButton;
         var route = button?.BindingContext as Routes;

        var token = Application.Current.Properties["MyToken"].ToString();
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);
        var response = await client.GetStringAsync("URL from questions and answers");
        List<Question> punkty = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Question>>(response);
        List<Question> list = new List<Question>();
        foreach (Question tmp in punkty)
        {
            if (tmp.RouteId == route.Id)
            {
                list.Add(tmp);
            }
        }


        await Navigation.PushAsync(new UserQuestionPage());
    }
```

Class Question:

```
  public class Question
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public IList<string> Answers { get; set; }
    public int GoodAnswer { get; set; }
    public string Question1 { get; set; }
    public int RouteId { get; set; }

}
```

I would like to see questions and answers in the UserQuestionPage class as a list. Sorry for my english.

Listview from routes

```
 <ListView Margin="0,0,0,0" x:Name="routesList"
            HorizontalOptions="Center"  
            VerticalOptions="Center"
            ItemTapped="OnTapped"
            SelectionMode="None"
            ItemsSource="{Binding Routes}"
            SeparatorColor="#90B320"
            HasUnevenRows="True">
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ViewCell>
                            <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical">
                                <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                                    <Label Text="Nr." TextColor="Black"
                                       FontAttributes="Bold" FontSize="15"
                                       HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                                       Margin="5,10,20,10"/>
                                    <Label Text="{Binding Id}" TextColor="Black"
                                       FontAttributes="Bold" FontSize="15"
                                       HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                                       Margin="-25,10,0,0"/>
                                    <Label Text="{Binding Name}"
                               TextColor="Black"
                               HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                               FontAttributes="Bold" 
                               FontSize="15"
                               Margin="20,10,20,10"/>
                                    <Label Text="{Binding Description}"
                               TextColor="Black"
                               HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                               VerticalTextAlignment="Center"
                               FontAttributes="Italic" 
                               FontSize="10"
                               Margin="10"/>
                                    <ImageButton x:Name="quizButton" Source="quiz2.png"
                                        HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                                        Clicked="OnQuizClicked" BackgroundColor="#FDDA8A" CornerRadius="20"
                                        WidthRequest="70" HeightRequest="70" Margin="3"/>
                                </StackLayout>
                            </StackLayout>
                        </ViewCell>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
```

Listview from UserQuestionPage:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Answers}" ItemTapped="ListView_ItemTapped"  Margin="10,0">

        </ListView>  



  public partial class UserQuestionPage : ContentPage
{
    public List<Question> pointsList = new List<Question>();

    Question pytania = new Question();
    public UserQuestionPage(RouteQuestions siema)
    {

        InitializeComponent();

        pointsList = siema.routeQuestions;

        foreach (Question tmp in siema.routeQuestions)
        {
            elo.ItemsSource = pointsList;

        }
    }
}

 public class RouteQuestions
{
    public RouteQuestions(List<Question> list)
    {
        routeQuestions = list;
    }
    public List<Question> routeQuestions { get; set; }



}
```

[I am sending a picture with a problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wamSV.png)

```
  <ListView x:Name="elo" ItemsSource="{Binding pointList}"  Margin="10,0">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <Grid>
                            <Label Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding Question1}" />
                            <Label Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Answers[0]}"/>
                            <Label Grid.Column="2" Text="{Binding Answers[1]}"/>
                            <Label Grid.Column="3" Text="{Binding Answers[2]}"/>
                            <Label Grid.Column="4" Text="{Binding Answers[3]}"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>


        </ListView>
```

[Next picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/awXfy.png)

Comment: you have posted some variation of this scenario multiple times.  It is still not clear what exactly you need help with.  You have not asked an actual question or stated a specific problem that you need help with.

Comment: Can you show some screenshot or drawing of what you trying to acheive?

Comment: Show us what the listView looks like then we can help you better.

Comment: Sorry, I corrected the post

Comment: Again, what **specifically** do you need help with?  You already have a ListView on your Routes page, so you already know how to create a ListView.  What problem do you have when creating a LIstView on the Questions page?

Comment: The problem is that I want to display from the API routes associated with questions and answers after pressing the ImageButton button. Compares RouteId with a click and writes it to the list.Add (tmp); I don't know how to forward this letter. Add (tmp) to the UserQuestionPage:

Comment: just pass the data as argument to the UserQuestionPage constructor

Comment: I understand, but I don't know what to do in UserQuestioPage to display it as a list.

Comment: is the data in `list` what you want to pass to UserQuestionPage?  If so, then just assign that as the ItemsSource of your list.  Just like you do with the other ListView you already have.

Comment: I already know how to do it in Xaml, but I still have a problem how to set it in the cs code ( in UserQuestionPage.xaml.cs)

Comment: `MyListView.ItemsSource = myData;`

Comment: How can I then refer to the Question class to get Answers and Question1? from the data in **list**

Comment: I added the class that I used and the picture with the problem

Comment: first, why are you assigning ItemsSource in a foreach loop?  What is the point of that?  Second, your ItemsSource appears to be a List<Question>, you just need to provide a DataTemplate in your XAML to format the display.

Comment: Thank you. Do you know how to display public IList <string> Answers in listview?

Comment: if Answers is a fixed length, you can just build them into your template using index notation ([0],[1], etc).  If they are not then you should probably consider a grouped ListView

Comment: Thank you. I did so with the question in the first column and the answers in the following columns. In api I have that when I press the appropriate line from 0 to 3, I will be able to choose the answer. How can I check that I have pressed this answer? I added another photo to the post.

Comment: use a RadioButton, not.a Label

Comment: How can I then set GoodAnswer (from api) as the correct answer?

Comment: figure out the index of the selected RadioButton and compare it to GoodAnswer.  There are many different ways you could do this.

Comment: I'm using sfRadioButton. How can I calculate the index?